# Connecting points to make a triangle

Tags: java, 3d, triangulation, point-clouds, 3d-reconstruction

If I have a set of 3d points (AKA point cloud) what is the best way to determine the groups of 3 points (triangles) I should make, to create a surface reconstruction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Delaunay Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) is your friend! There are lots of resources available about it if you Google the term, and the math/logic behind it isn't too tough. Making it FAST is a bit harder (but totally do-able), but that depends entirely on your requirements.

Comment: +1 Happy 2000!  I spent a nice few moments googling around "computational geometry" and "voronoi".  It seems the main advantage of Delaunay Triangulation is the constraint that angles be modest, which avoids some of the skinny triangles in a simpler Voronoi tessellation.  Adding "java" to the google search turns up plenty of libraries and so on.

Comment: If I were implementing this from scratch, out of curiosity, I'd start with one of the simpler algorithms here, perhaps "divide and conquer":  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Algorithms

Comment: Last time I implemented it was for a pre-process, so it could be as slow as I wanted. Turned out a simple brute force was fast enough for most of my needs at the time. I recommend implementing the brute force version at least once, just to get a feel for how it works. Then optimize away! (Oh, and If I recall correctly this algorithm is just BEGGING to be multi-threaded.)

Comment: Delaunay Triangulation really only works for 2D. You can do 3D if the points are on a surface and you can map them onto sensible 2D coords (like lat/lon) - otherwise you need Poisson, ball pivoting or marching cubes

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use an external application (or implement your own), [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) has lots of cool reconstruction algorithms under: *Filters > Re-meshing, simplification and reconstruction*. **Ball Pivoting Surface Reconstruction** and **Poisson Reconstruction** are good ones.

Answer (score 0):

A new approach has been introduced by Vierjahn et al. [sGNG: Online Surface Reconstruction based on Growing Neural Gas](http://viscg.uni-muenster.de/publications/2013/VHHM13/). Although it is a rather complex algorithm to implement it allows incremental refinements of the 3D mesh.

You can read the tech report [here](http://viscg.uni-muenster.de/publications/2013/VHHM13/techreport-fin.pdf). Furthermore, the authors give hints and refer to other new techniques in the research field of 3D mesh reconstruction from 3D point clouds.